# Qual a diferença entre printf e fprintf em C?

Tags: c, printf

Minha dúvida é simples assim mesmo: Qual a diferença entre printf e fprintf em C?

Vi respostas para Java, mas como não sei nada de Java não sei se tem a ver.

Por exemplo, no trecho de código a seguir, aparece um printf e um fprintf:

switch (opt) {

```
        case 's':
            saida=optarg;
            printf("Nome do arquivo de saida: %s\n", saida);
            errS++;
            break;

        case 'e':
            entrada=optarg;
            printf("Nome do arquivo de entrada: %s\n", entrada);
            errE++;
            break;


        case '?':
            fprintf(stderr, "\nFALTA PARAMETROS\n");

        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "%s \nparametros:\n-e arquivo de entrada\n-s arquivo de saida\n", argv[0]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo direcionamento, quando pesquisei não encontrei o tópico citado.